# i am not getting the output in the console. The output window simply popup when i run my code in dev c++ but not showing any output

Tags: c, pointers

i have tried this same code in online compiler and got the correct output. But in dev C++ i am getting blank output console.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int main(){
  float a[5],*ptr,val;
  int i,flag=0;
  ptr=a;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      scanf("%f",ptr+i);
  }
  printf("\n enter the value to be searched");
  scanf("%f",&val);
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      if(*(ptr+i)==val){
          flag=1;
          break;
      }
   }
   if(flag==1){
      printf("\n element found");
   }
   else
      printf("\n not found");
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Put `\n` at the end of your `printf()` strings. The output is being buffered.

Comment: Did you provide some input?

Comment: The code works fine, it's probably just a quirk of the Dev-C++ console.

Comment: Can't reproduce on MS VC, but the code does lack any prompt telling you to enter five values, so the first thought is "this has hung". But there should be at least *some* output after making the entries, because there are some newlines (although in the wrong places). You could try `fflush(stdout)` affter each `printf` too.

Comment: The prompt to input values is coming *after* the `scanf` loop.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that is needed for the next entry. The first prompt is missing.